# Typescript using bracket notation to access optional properties of an object

Tags: typescript

I have an object, which is of type defined there:

```
interface IObject extends IIndexable {
  foo?: string;
  foo2?: string;
  foo3?: string;
}
```

My `IIndexable` looks like this:

```
interface IIndexable {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

I want to access its properties using brackets notation like this:

```
let object: IObject = {};
object["foo"] = "bar";
```

The problem is that key defined in `IIndexable` can only be of type of `string` or `number` and because my objects' keys are all optional, they are of type `string | undefined`. Error message I get is:

> Property 'fullName' of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.

I cannot make my objects' keys not optional, because my object sometimes can be empty.
I also tried to make objects' type `IObject | {}`, but that way I still cannot access its properties.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need `extends IIndexable` part?

Comment: @Aleksey L. I use `IIndexable` in other places where I need to access objects using brackets notation. It's the same as putting `[key: string]: string;` line at the end of interface where I need this access.

Comment: You can access props with brackets notation without defining index signature

Comment: Without it I get this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IObject'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IObject'.

Comment: Yes, that's because you're trying to access it with random string instead of known property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) (instead of interface) and use [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) with the `IIndexable`:

```
type IObject = IIndexable & {
  foo?: string;
  foo2?: string;
  foo3?: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKpAEwgDzgIwBsUBvAKGWQG0BrCATwC5kBnMKUAcwF1m2OQnANxkAvmTJh6ABxSoA8vgBWEBGGQBeNBmx4iKAGTJylGAHszAfj7suI0xYBM11rcH3k5swGYX-O2ISxOpmyqpgzAphaprGoiKhKmpUAEReKdyxKfhwUClCQA)